# Woocommerce product shortcodes do not display products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-shortcode

I face a problem with displaying products on a specific portfolio post. I use product **shortcodes** in order to display specific products, but they do not appear.

I use **wordpress 5.2.5**, **avada theme 5.9.1** and **woocommerce 3.9.2**.

Anyone got an idea what is going on?

If not, can anyone tell me an alternative way to display them?

Answer (score 0):

use shortcode [get_specific_product_shortcode id='here enter product id']

```
    function get_specific_product_shortcode_function($atts){

  extract( shortcode_atts(
        array(
           'id' => '',
            ), $atts )
    );

    ob_start();

    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page'   => 1,
        'post__in'         =>array($id),
        'orderby'          => 'date',
        'order'            => 'DESC',
        'post_type'        => 'product',
        'post_status'      => 'publish',
    );

    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    $count = $query->found_posts;

    if($query->have_posts()){

        while( $query->have_posts() ) {  $query->the_post();

                $post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();

                 $product = wc_get_product(get_the_ID());

                if (!empty($post_thumbnail_id)) {
                    $image_size = 'medium'; // (thumbnail, medium, large, full or custom size)
                    $img_url_arr = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $post_thumbnail_id, $image_size );
                    $img_url = $img_url_arr[0];

                }else{
                    //placeholder image
                    $img_url = home_url().'/wp-content/uploads/woocommerce-placeholder.png';


                }

            ?>
            <div>
                <a href="<?php echo get_permalink();?>">
                    <img src="<?php echo $img_url?>" style="width: 150px;">
                </a>

                <div>Price: <?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?></div>

                <div><?php echo get_the_title();?></div>
            </div>
            <?php
        }

        wp_reset_postdata();

    }else{
        echo 'no post'; echo "<br>";
    }



return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('get_specific_product_shortcode', 'get_specific_product_shortcode_function');
```